# how to do reverse operation of SVD in opencv?

Tags: svd

I am applying SVD on image using opencv 2.4.9 command SVDecomp. at the time of back substitution it asks rhs array.What is that array?

commands:

```
     1. cv::SVDecomp(im_enc1,w,u,vt);
```

where w,u,vt are SVD components and im_enc1 is inputimage.

```
     2. cv::SVBackSubst(w,u,vt,rhs,im_enc2);
```

where w,u,vt are SVD components and im_enc2 is output image.

Answer (score 0):

SVD is a decomposition of a matrix:

```
[ u, w, vt ] = svd( mx );
```

So the reverse should be a composition (matrix product):

```
mx = u * w * vt;
```

Difficulties might arise from representation of w. Consider following:
[Matlab SVD output in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029486/matlab-svd-output-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

If you yield `u` `w` `vt` by

```
 cv::SVD::compute(img,w,u,vt);
```

Then the way you reserve SVD to get img is

```
 img = u*cv::Mat::diag(w)*vt;
```

Note that `w` computed by `cv::SVD::compute` is a `n*1` vector instead of a `n*n` matrix.